# Memory Leak with readFile

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

**Node-v12.14.2**

I'm using the same code here and I observe no memory leak here.
[image]

readFileHandle takes around 48MB of memory.

**Node-v16.14.2**

When I updated to node 16 the memory leak is happening which is observed with the readFile function of fs.

[image]

readFileHandle takes around 101MB of memory.

I'm running the same code in both cases, while the garbage collection is happening in the case of node 12, in node 16 the memory keeps on increasing without being released.

In the below code, I'm reading a file from the path and passing it to another function for adding a few details and then returning the data back to the function where it was invoked.
If possible I want to release the memory that's stored by readFile in memory once the execution is done.

Code:

```
const readData = () => {
    const jsCode = await fs.readFile('/path', {'utf8'})
    const data = requireString(jsCode) // Add few details
    return data;
}

const handleRoute = () => {
    const comp = readData();
}
```

Comment: [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: `{'utf8'}` seems like invalid syntax

Comment: If this is a clear regression from node 12 to node 16, and you have a simple repro, I'm sure the nodejs dev team would be happy about a bug report